# How getting default Printer attribute setting

Tags: java, printing, printers

I was wondering how it is possible to get the default printer attribute setting using PrintServiceAttributeSet . 
For example before printing from a printer i need to know the current printer attribute setting like Chromaticity. Based on that return value I need to set the printer to the new attribute setting.
Can anyone help me out. 
Is it possible to get some sample code to get and set this attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference [How do I get print service attribute set?](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-print-service-attribute-set/):

> This example demonstrates how to get print service’s attribute set
>   using the `javax.print` API. First we find the default printer for the
>   current machine using the `PrintServiceLookup` class. This will give us
>   a `PrintService` object, this object might be null if no print service
>   found.
>
> The final step is to get the print service attribute set by calling
>   `getAttributes()` method of the `PrintService`. We can convert the
>   returned `AttributeSet` into an array using the `toArray()` method and
>   iterate it.

```
package org.kodejava.example.print;

import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.attribute.Attribute;
import javax.print.attribute.AttributeSet;

public class PrinterAttribute {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //
        // Locates the default print service for this environment.
        //
        PrintService printer =
                PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        if (printer != null) {
            //
            // Getting print service's attribute set.
            //
            AttributeSet attributes = printer.getAttributes();
            for (Attribute a : attributes.toArray()) {
                String name = a.getName();
                String value = attributes.get(a.getClass()).toString();
                System.out.println(name + " : " + value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to know the configuration of the printer
ie: if I forcibly imprimente to print in black and white, orientation, the chosen format ...
this method just returns the default printer and
displayed if color-supported, queued-job-count ...

Comment: The anser is exaclty what you asked for :) "how it is possible to get the default printer attribute setting using PrintServiceAttributeSet"

Comment: See [Working with Print Services and Attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/services.html) when you need to set attributes

Comment: @Yanni What is **imprimene**?

Comment: Ok :) I rephrase my question how can I know the configuration settings of a printer